# VBA change value in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help changing variables in another workbook.

First I open the workbook with `Workbooks.Open ("test.xlsx")`

When I try to change a cell value with `Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(1, 1).Value = VariableX` it gives me error 9: subscript out of range. I don't see why it won't work. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: your sheet name is "Sheet"?

Comment: That's an example, but the name of the sheet is right.

Comment: Your opening the same workbook `test.xlsx` instead of the other. So you don't have there `Sheet` worksheet..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Workbooks.open` Returns a Workbook-object. Use this to reference the Workbook you want to manipulate:

```
dim wb as Workbook
set wb = Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx")
wb.Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(1,1).Value = variableX

' Close the workbook afterwards and save the changes
wb.Close True
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have `Open`ed the workbook, it is `Active`.  Here is a small working example:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim VariableX As Long
    VariableX = 123

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\Book1.xlsx"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = VariableX

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition!