# VBA Excel taking control of the cells on the another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to link the cells on the external Excel file with the cells from my active workbook.

I found something quite good here:

[VBA change value in another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824107/vba-change-value-in-another-workbook)

and tried to combine this code with mine:

```
 Sub Splicing()
 Dim VariableX As Long
 VariableX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D10").Value
 Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Splicing Template_V1.0.xlsx"
 Workbooks.Open (Path)
 Worksheets("Frontsheet").Cells(4, 10).Value = VariableX

 End Sub
```

The debugger says: **Type mismatch**

Is there any way to link these cells between two separate workbooks?

[image]

Comment: The content in `D10` is not a `Long`, but a `String`. Or just use `Variant`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I changed. Now the file is opening, but nothing changed.

Comment: You aren't using the workbook you opened. You are grabbing a value from a workbook, opening a different workbook, then pasting the value right back to where you got it from.

Comment: You're never even accessing the other workbook. VariableX is from FrontSheet and then you assign  a cell value on front sheet  = Variable X

Comment: @Warcupine this is what I need in VBA :) So far the Code for the opening workbook is wirking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Splicing()
 Dim VariableX As string
 Dim newbook as workbook
 VariableX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D10").Value
 Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Splicing Template_V1.0.xlsx"
 set newbook = Workbooks.Open(Path)
 newbook.sheets("Frontsheet").Cells(4, 10).Value = VariableX 'Not sure if this is the right worksheet name

 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I have now. The file is opening, but no changes have been reported inside.

Comment: If your picture is the two workbooks then the cell you are trying to write to already as the same value so you won't see a change.

Comment: Let me replace the picture then. Sorry I put just wrong

Comment: Works for me, Though ```Cells(4, 10)``` is row 4 column J Not row 10 Column D

Comment: Yeah! That's true. Because I have I and J merged I couldn't see the result. Now is correct. I am very grateful for your hint. Thanks!